# $(\phi: A \rightarrow A\wedge \phi \text{ strictly increasing})\rightarrow(\forall a \in A \phi(a)\geq a)\implies A \text{ well ordered}$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $(A,<)$ be a total order.

Is the following true?

> $\forall \phi: A \rightarrow A((\phi \text{ strictly increasing})\rightarrow(\forall a \in A \phi(a)\geq a))\implies A \text{ well ordered}$

We know that the opposite implication is true, but I can't prove or disprove the above assertion.

I think that the thesis is false but I was not able to find a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, right, I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry dcolazin, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean the left hand side of the implication to have $\forall \phi : A \to A$ in it?  i.e. is the conjecture that if every strictly increasing function is inflationary, then $A$ is well ordered?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I meant

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the question (so I deleted my answer). I see you have edited your question to clarify that now.

Comment: See my answer to the same question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72935/ .

Comment: Thank you Andreas Blass, that answers the question